# How to keep the publishM2 task in sbt from adding version numbers?

Tags: scala, sbt

The publishM2 task in sbt adds version numbers to some of of our artifacts. E.g. "logging.conf" winds up in the repository as "logging-1.1.1.conf". Can we turn this of?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no snippet of you build.sbt, all I can help with is to point you to documentation - [Modifying default artifacts](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Artifacts.html#Modifying+default+artifacts) - you should be able to specify the name for logging.conf to not have module.revision